# I want to developed one app upon API 17 but I haven't build tool version 17 so how it is possible?

Tags: android

Please help me regarding developing android app. If I developed that app upon API 21 or 23 then Is it run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that version of **build tool**.

In the `build.gradle`, set `minSdkVersion` or `targetSdkVersion` (or both) to API-17. For your case below is recommended:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    ...
}
```